# Can bluetooth LE detect a touch using proximity?

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-low-energy

How accurate is the proximity feature in BLE, can I detect if two BLE are touched tougether?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "proximity" feature in BLE is actually based on signal strength of the packets it receives  (RSSI).

The RSSI changes very little with distance when the devices are far away, and disturbances play a large role in the RSSI value making it a very unreliable as a direct distance measure in the far field.

However when you bring two devices close to each other (<1m), the RSSI starts to grow exponentially and therefore the different disturbance play little role in the RSSI value compared to the distance.

While it is impossible to detect millimetre differences, i.e. plastic bits actually touching vs 1mm apart, you can get about 10cm accuracy when the antennas are near to each other. Please do note that this will be somewhat dependent on the antenna design of both devices, meaning to get very accurate you would need to measure the exact setup with the devices.

Answer (score 0):

I did some work on proximity with iPhones talking to CSR1001/1001 devices and found the RSSI to be highly variable depending on a number of factors.  My experience was it was difficult to detect distance any kind of accuracy.  E.g. moving 15 metres away (line of sight) has the same effect as putting the item in your pocket.  It is very much NOT a tape measure.

However, the once case where it is reasonably consistent, is when the units are very close together, so if you want some kind of 'tap here to do something' operation then you might be ok.  But even then it might work from 25cm away on tuesday but only 3cm away on wednesday because of battery strength / the user having foil underpants / the phase of the moon.